# Adjust level of detail of Openstreetmap on specific zoom

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, zoom

I need an overview of a specific large area on QGIS Desktop 2.16.0.
The details disappears with this level of zoom.

Is it possible to control the display level ?

If I zoom too much, I can't see all the concerned area.
[image]

If I unzoom, I lose details[image].

---

From the answer I was able to show details:

[image]

However is it possible to get this bigger and clearer like this ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Christ974! You could hold down **Ctrl** when zooming which allows you to zoom in and out at a reduced level :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can overwrite the current scale in the status bar. Just try out at which scale the next zoom level gets activated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can identify at which scale the level gets activated. The problem is that i can't take a screenshot of the entire area with this level.

Comment: Probably you don't want to make a screenshot (since you're limited by your screen's size and resolution) but export as an image so you can control de image size and dpi. You may want to try qgis composer as well, as you can easily control the scale, and then export it to raster or vectorial images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand from the discussion on the comments, what you want to do is to generate an image of a large area, which is so big that does not fit on your screen and, hence, you have to zoom out, resulting in a loss of detail.

In order to export large areas, you may want to use QGIS' built-in [Print Composer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html), this way you can control map's scale (which, as @Andrej stated, you can figure out which scale level has the detail you want to).

After that, you can export the image into a Raster or vector format, and most importantly, you won't be limited by your screen's size or resolution, as you can choose the image's resolution and dpi.

The summarised process would be as follows:

1. Open Print composer from `Project\New Print Composer (CTRL+P)` Give
   your composition a name (it can be anything)
2. Select a page size from the right panel (`Composition` tab). That will be your canvas.
3. Insert a map into the canvas with the following icon [![enter image
   description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ht2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ht2.png)
4. Select the map and change its scale properties in the right panel (`Item properties` tab)
5. Click on export to image icon ([image]) or export to svg icon ([image]).
6. Select image's properties, give it a name and store it into a known
   location.