# Control level of detail of OpenStreetMap/ESRI map using QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.4 and tried to print a map covering a fixed region which has a fixed lat lon boundary. The print composer gives me too many details whereas I just want the main highways.

I am wondering if there a way to control the level of detail shown in the print composer so that the certain level of detail will be shown no matter how much I zoom in? For example, I want to print the region covered in Figure 2 with the level of detail in Figure 1.

[image: Figure 1: Level of detail wanted]

[image: Figure 2: Coverage of the map wanted]

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247173/adjust-level-of-detail-of-openstreetmap-on-specific-zoom?rq=1 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292778/how-can-i-show-the-details-from-the-highest-zoom-of-osm-webmaps-in-qgis-for-prin?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you use a tile-based basemap (OSM, ESRI, Google or whatever), you can not change anything on the styling. Vector tiles would be a better solution, but QGIS is not yet ready for them.

You can however download OSM raw data, and style it on your own. Geofabrik offers country-wide subdatasets, and the QuickOSM plugin of OSM lets you download filtered data of the current map view.

To speed up rendering, you should have only the topics that you intend to draw in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is really helpful! I am able to just download the major highways in the QuickOSM plugin, but I am wondering if there is also a way for the plugin to download the associated highway name/number too?

Comment: The numbered highways might be organized in relations. So you have to download these too.